# Should each VM get a dedicated tap to a virtual bridge?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a networking setup involving three VM's that is working, but I'm not quite sure it is optimal.

Put simply - given a virtual bridge defined on the host, should each guest VM access that bridge via a *dedicated* tap, or can each such guest use the same tap?

I presently have an Ubuntu server with an internal network enslaved to a bridge. I then have a single tap defined on that bridge. I then, in turn, use that tap for each of three guest VM's to access the bridge. This all works the way I intend, but....

It occurs to me that by using the single tap, I'm routing each VM's networking through (ultimately) a single file descriptor (if my understanding of virtual taps/bridges is even close to right). That leads me to wonder if perhaps my setup - while working - is not optimal. Is it preferable to create multiple taps, one for each VM?

Thanks.

p.s. The three VM's include two Linux boxes and a 64-bit Windows 7 box.

Comment: According to the VBox docs, you don't need to use taps any longer, you can, but they're not necessary. https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html  "Even though TAP is no longer necessary on Linux with bridged networking, you can still use TAP interfaces for certain advanced setups, since you can connect a VM to any host interface -- which could also be a TAP interface."